# Help regarding how to type a long equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, errors

If we have a long equation, how to typeset it successfully?

After running the following lines I am not able get any output:

```
\documentclass[11]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 g(x)=\frac{1}{8x^3}[\frac{(x^2+2x)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n+1}
                     -x^4(\frac{(x^2+2x)^{n-1}}{n-1}-\frac{{x^{2n-2}{n-1})]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Could somebody please tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `11` document class option doesn't do anything. If you want the main document font size to be 11pt, you must specify `11pt`, not `11`.

Comment: I think the lesson of the accepted answer is that the first step in "how to type" is to make sure you're not getting any errors.  The equation being long was not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extra `{` (and missing `\left` and `\right`)?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    g(x)=\frac{1}{8x^3}\left[\frac{(x^2+2x)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{x^{2n+2}}{n+1}-x^4\left(\frac{(x^2+2x)^{n-1}}{n-1}-\frac{x^{2n-2}}{n-1}\right)\right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: equation]

Comment: so kind of you @Ivan.Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome @sajjadveeri. Would you mind accepting my answer on the page?

Comment: sure.I did accept it.